# How can I show a full screen view with angular's ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and I have the following index view:

```
<div ng-include="'/views/topbar.html'"></div>
<div class="vm-view">
    <div class="container-fluid" ui-view></div>
</div>
```

So, all the content will be loaded under the top bar. Thats ok, but I need to **render a single view without the top bar (full screen)**. I want to do this without use [named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views). I want to preserve the index structure intact and states hierarchy too.

Comment: What about binding it to a $rootScope value like $rootScope.fullscreen? And then <div ng-if="fullscreen" ng-include="'/views/topbar.html'"></div>. It's a bit ugly. But I guess it will work. Even better if you have values that can determine if the it should be fullscreen. Then you could use that in you ngIf-expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add some class depending on current state to hide topbar

```
<div ng-controller="someCtrl">
    <div ng-class="{hide:isSpecialState()}" ng-include="'/views/topbar.html'"></div>
    <div class="vm-view">
        <div class="container-fluid" ui-view></div>
    </div>
</div>

app.controller('someCtrl', function($state) {
    $scope.isSpecialState = function() {
        return $state.is('<STATE_NAME>');
    };
})
```

Comment: This is the workaround that I used to solve the problem. I want a better solution...